# Convert a dataframe column with string to numeric

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe

```
d = {'s': '3.4E-4'}
df = pd.Dataframe(d)
```

I want to convert this to numeric

```
pd.to_numeric(df['s'], errors='coerce')
```

This doesn't work because of the presence of `-` I think.

Any suggestion on how to convert the string to numeric?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you posted gives errors, but you can change the type to whatever you want. Numeric could be float (which is what you would need) or int:

```
d = {'s': '3.4E-4'}
df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=[0])
df['s'] = df['s'].astype(float)
```